# jQuery Insert closing div tag and opeing div tag after count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get jquery to close a div and inset an opening div with a class after x amount of items.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$(this).after('</div> <div class=\"bar">Bar');
```

it outputs:

```
<div class="bar">Bar</div>
```

What I need is:

```
<div class="item2">
   <div class="CountThese2"> Count Me </div>
   <div class="CountThese2"> Count Me </div>
</div>
<div class="bar">
   <div class="CountThese2"> Count Me </div>
   <div class="CountThese2"> Count Me </div>
</div>
   <div class="bar">
   <div class="CountThese2"> Count Me </div>
<div class="CountThese2"> Count Me </div>
</div>
<div class="bar">
   <div class="CountThese2"> Count Me </div>
   <div class="CountThese2"> Count Me </div>    
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yoderman94/JEtj2/

Comment: Why doesn't your fiddle match up with what you have posted here?

Answer (score 2):

You can't add half a tag. I think what you're trying to do is wrap the elements. Your fiddle is pretty messy, but here's a simple example of how you can do that:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Q62H/

```
while($('#wrapper > a:lt(2)').wrapAll('<div class="bar">bar</div>').length) { }
```

Which turns this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">1</a>
</div>
```

into this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="bar">bar
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">1</a>
    </div>    
    <div class="bar">bar
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">1</a>
    </div>    
    <div class="bar">bar
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">1</a>
    </div>    
    <div class="bar">bar
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">1</a>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: You lose text nodes this way, so all the links are smashed together, with no whitespace between them.

Answer (score 1):

You can't manipulate the DOM that way, with or without jQuery.  To accomplish the same thing, insert a new div after the current div's parent, and then move all of the current div's following siblings to the new div:

```
var bar = $("<div>").addClass("bar").text("Bar");
bar.insertAfter($(this).parent());
bar.append($(this).nextAll());
```

**Edit:** To preserve text nodes, including the whitespace between your links, it's not quite as simple as `$(this).nextAll()`, sadly.  You need to use `.contents()` to select the text nodes, then slice at the index of `this`:

```
var contents = $(this).parent().contents();
var bar = $("<div>").addClass("bar").text("Bar");
bar.insertAfter($(this).parent());
bar.append(contents.slice(contents.index(this) + 1));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JEtj2/6/

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to recommend a different approach here. When you call `.after()` you need to be giving it a complete open and close tag. You cannot open a tag then close it later like you are trying to above.

My advice would be to try and take an approach like the following, so you can pass a complete open and close tag to `.after()`

```
var theDiv = "<div class='bar'>";
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    theDiv += '<div class="CountThese2"> Count Me </div>';
}
theDiv += "</div>";

$('#thing').after(theDiv);
```

See how I constructed the whole div including contents before calling `.after()` ?